# Deselect multiple fields from a query in VBA from MS-Access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I need to deselect some specific values in some columns, like the word "Stamping" in the *AREA RESP* column, and I need to get the ones that a date in the range from today to 30 days later.

I tried with this:

```vb
myQuery = "SELECT ORDER, [PART NUMBER], [DEPT RESP], [AREA RESP], [START DATE]" _
            & " FROM INITIAL_PHASE" _
            & " WHERE [PLANNER NAME] = 'Homer' OR [PLANNER NAME] = 'Bart'" _
            & "    OR [PLANNER NAME] = 'Marge' AND [AREA RESP] <> 'Stamping'" _
            & "   AND [START DATE] BETWEEN " & DateToday & " AND " & DateMonth
            & "   AND [PART NUMBER] NOT LIKE '%R'" _
            & " ORDER BY [START DATE]"
```

But it returns *Stamping* and all the dates that it finds

```vb
Sub GetFromMSAccess()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim SH As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim myQuery As String
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim DateToday As Date
    Dim DateMonth As Date

    DateToday = Format(Date, "m/d/yyyy")
    DateMonth = DateToday + 30 'One full month starting from today

    Application.StatusBar = "Extracting data from MS-Access"

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Sheets("DataSheet").Select

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set SH = WB.Sheets("DataSheet")

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=G:\Share\Control\MD\Master_data.mdb;" & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=321pass;"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

    'Here it gets the information I need
        With SH
            Set Rng = .Cells(2, "A")
        End With

        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

        myQuery = "SELECT ORDER, [PART NUMBER], [DEPT RESP], [AREA RESP], [START DATE] " & _
                    "FROM INITIAL_PHASE WHERE [PLANNER NAME] = 'Homer' OR [PLANNER NAME] = 'Bart' OR [PLANNER NAME] = 'Marge' " & _
                    "AND [AREA RESP] <> 'Stamping' AND [START DATE] BETWEEN " & DateToday & " AND " & DateMonth & " " & _
                    "and [PART NUMBER] not LIKE '%R' order by [START DATE]"

        rst.Open myQuery, strConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic

        Rng.CopyFromRecordset rst
        rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

I want to get the ones that doesn't have the word "Stamping" and any other date outside from the range I want.

Comment: Try replacing: [PLANNER NAME] = 'Homer' OR [PLANNER NAME] = 'Bart' OR [PLANNER NAME] = 'Marge' with PLANNER_NAME in ('Homer', 'Bart', 'Marge')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially your `OR` and `AND` logic are conflating with each other. You need to include parentheses around the `OR` conditions to be consider one separate condition inclusive with other `AND` conditions.

Additionally, there is no reason to concatenate SQL in VBA. `Date()`,`Time()`, `Now()` are available in MS Access SQL:

```vb
myQuery = "SELECT ORDER, [PART NUMBER], [DEPT RESP], [AREA RESP], [START DATE]" _
            & " FROM INITIAL_PHASE" _
            & " WHERE ([PLANNER NAME] = 'Homer' OR [PLANNER NAME] = 'Bart' OR [PLANNER NAME] = 'Marge')" _
            & "   AND [AREA RESP] <> 'Stamping'" _
            & "   AND [START DATE] BETWEEN Date() AND Date() + 30" _
            & "   AND [PART NUMBER] NOT LIKE '%R'" _
            & " ORDER BY [START DATE]"
```

Even better because this is a pure SQL query and you are using `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses that can be index-able, save your query as an MS Access stored query  and avoid any SQL in VBA. Stored queries are more efficient than string-built SQL run on the fly since the Access engine saves best execution plan for saved queries.

```vb
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "mySavedQuery", strConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(2, "A").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! And also thanks for the extra information, I'm just an intern who is still learning VBA